# Set aspect ratio via pseudo element and prevent element from overflowing

Tags: html, css

I have a layout like this:

```css
body {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#interaktiivne-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
}

#interaktiivne-videowrapper:after {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: brown;
}

#interaktiivne-videowrapper>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}

#interaktiivne-videowrapper>div>video {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Interaktiivne</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="interaktiivne-container">
    <div id="interaktiivne-videowrapper">
      <div>
        <video autoplay src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4"></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this gives me the desired width for the video. Problem now is, that in some content cases, I want to resize the video element itself to 200%. but this MUST NOT make the container div's expand and the overflow MUST STAY HIDDEN.. the code currently, sadly does do it, overflow is not hidden :( Any ideas?

Comment: `position: relative;` need to be on `#interaktiivne-videowrapper>div` or `#interaktiivne-videowrapper`

Comment: @TemaniAfif that causes my video to hide with 0 height :(

Comment: in addition you add `html{height:100%}`

Comment: @TemaniAfif video height still 0

Comment: you need to continue the cascading height .. you are missing many of them